# Mega2560 has 2 Crystal Oscillator?

Tags: arduino-mega

Who knows this Mega2560 with two Crystal Oscillators: 12 000 MHz and 16 000 MHz? What is the use of them?

Comment: there is an ATmega16u2 as USB converter. it has the 12 MHz oscilator

Comment: Don't the 16U2s also use 16 MHz, while the CH340 use 12 MHz?  The 2560 itself more typically use a  smaller 3-pin16 MHz resonator.

Comment: Please expand on your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two devices on an Arduino board than need a clock source:

- The ATMega328 / ATMega2560 main MCU (16MHz)
- The USB interface.

The USB interface crystal speed depends on what device is used on your board. Genuine Arduino boards use an ATMega16U2 which uses a 16MHz crystal.  Cheap Chinese clones use a CH340G which takes a 12MHz crystal.

Note that normally it's one crystal and one ceramic resonator.  USB requires very precise timing, so a crystal is used for that. The main MCU doesn't need quite such precise timing, so a cheaper (and less accurate) ceramic resonator is used.